# Inno Setup: Download setup .bin slice files before installation starts

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

I am trying to create a distributable .exe file with Inno Setup tools and Inno Download Plugin. The resulting file is ~3GB in size, split in 6 parts (1 for the executable, 5 bins containing all the files).

Would it be possible to keep the 5 bins uploaded on some server and download them during installation with the remaining executable file?

My code is here :

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  ResultCode: integer;
  TempAddress: String;
  FinalSavePath: String;
  UserName, UserCompany: String;
begin
  idpSetOption('DetailedMode',  '1');
  idpSetOption('AllowContinue', '1');

  idpSetLogin('aaa', 'aaa');

  idpAddFile('https://...', target_path);
  idpAddFile('https://...', target_path);
  idpAddFile('https://...', target_path);
  idpAddFile('https://...', target_path);
  idpDownloadAfter(wpWelcome);
end;
```

With `idpDownloadAfter(wpWelcome)` the installer starts downloading right after accepting to run the executable, if `.bin` files are already present. If not, the installer just keeps asking for the `.bin` to be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Inno Setup 6.1 has a built-in support for file downloads, which does not need any support files. So the solution below is obsolete now. See [Inno Setup: Install file from Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887428/850848#66100456)*.

---

Inno Download Plugin uses `idp.dll`, which itself is stored in the `mysetup-*.bin` files. That's why you get prompted for the `.bin` files, even before anything starts. You need the `idp.dll` so that the download itself can start.

With some hacking you can have the `idp.dll` be stored in the `[Code]`, hence directly in the `mysetup.exe`.
See [Inno Setup: Reading a file from installer during uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37552286/850848).

You will need to modify the `idp.iss` as follows:

- Remove the `[Files]` section with its reference to `idp.dll`.
- In all the `external` functions declarations:
  change `@files:idp.dll cdecl` to `@{tmp}\idp.dll cdecl delayload`.

To the front of your `.iss` script, copy the long code block from [my answer to the previously mentioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37552286/850848#37560872).

And now you can do:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  SaveBinaryStringToFile(
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\idp.dll'), {#FileToBinaryString("unicode\idp.dll")});

  idpAddFile(
    'https://www.example.com/mysetup-1.bin', ExpandConstant('{src}\mysetup-1.bin'));

  idpDownloadAfter( {whatever} );
end;
```

Make sure you update the path to the `idp.dll` to the correct location on your development machine in the call to `FileToBinaryString`.

*The code is for [Unicode version of Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43158677/850848) (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).*