# Embed file data into / retreive file data from Inno Setup

Tags: hex, inno-setup, pascalscript

Based on these posts,

[Writing binary file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617829/writing-binary-file-in-inno-setup)

[Inno Setup: Reading a file from installer during uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37552286/inno-setup-reading-a-file-from-installer-during-uninstallation)

What is the full code to embed the Bitmap image data into Inno Setup during compile and retrieve it during the installation?

This is required during uninstall process. Because this code does not work at uninstall:

```
ExtractTemporaryFile('myimage.bmp');
```

The file cannot be copied during the installation. It should be only retrieved during uninstallation.

Comment: *"the full code to embed the Bitmap image data into Inno Setup during compile and retrieve it during the installation"* is in my answer to [Inno Setup: Reading a file from installer during uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37552286/850848) – If you have some problem, we need [mcve].

Comment: What variable decides the hex code created?

Comment: I do not understand what you ask for.

Comment: This one `LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(
  BitmapImage.Bitmap, '4D5A50000200000004000F00FFFF0000B800000....');`

Comment: That's not a question. What about it? What variable? You do not put that hex code into your code manually. The hex code is generated. In your code you will use something like `LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(BitmapImage.Bitmap, {#FileToBinaryString("C:\path\WizModernSmallImage.bmp")});`. As my answer says.

Comment: Yes, but what variable saves the hex code that is generated? I mean, how to find the hex code generated?

Comment: You do not! The `FileToBinaryString` does that for you! Your code will be `LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(BitmapImage.Bitmap, {#FileToBinaryString("C:\path\WizModernSmallImage.bmp")});`, **NOT** `LoadBitmapFromBinaryString(BitmapImage.Bitmap, '4D5A50000200000004000F00FFFF0000B800000....');`